# Unable to set screen brightness - xubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, brightness, backlight, nomodeset

Here are *my issues* :

- I can't change the **screen brightnesss** on my laptop. The keyboard combinations made for it **(Fn+F5, Fn+F6) do not work**. I read that the desktop environment (Xfwm, or Xfce, I don't know the difference as both appear to be installed) should provide some **addon buttons to set the screen brightness**, but I could not find such options so far.
- I cannot use the keys combination desined to **turn on/off the light from my laptop keys** (Fn+F3 and Fn+F4)

*My pc :* Asus GL553VD, i7-7700HQ, Nvidia 1050, with Windows 10 x64 preinstalled, and an UEFI bios.

I could only install my linux distro (Xubuntu 16.04) using the "**nomodeset**" option in the bios. ("acpi=off" did not allow Linux to start)

*Previous attempts and possibly useful info :*

1. In the `etc/default/grub` file, I tried to replace "nomodeset" with "acpi_backlight=vendor", "acpi_backlight=native", "acpi_backlight=video". These prevented Linux to start so I switched back to nomodeset.
2. I installed xblacklight but when I get the error "No outputs have backlight property" when typing e.g. "xblacklight =50"
3. My folder `sys/class/backlight` also happens to empty though I don't really understand whether it is important.
4. The `sudo find /sys/ -type f -iname '*brightness*'` command gave me several entries that are :

   /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/leds/phy0-led/max_brightness
   /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/leds/phy0-led/brightness
   /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::capslock/max_brightness
       /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::capslock/brightness
   /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::numlock/max_brightness
   /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::numlock/brightness
   /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::scrolllock/max_brightness
   /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::scrolllock/brightness
   /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/ATK4002:00/leds/asus-wireless::airplane/max_brightness
   /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/ATK4002:00/leds/asus-wireless::airplane/brightness
   /sys/module/video/parameters/brightness_switch_enabled
   /sys/module/i915/parameters/invert_brightness

The second file ('`/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/leds/phy0-led/brightness`') only contains the value "1" but I did not manage to edit it.

5. typing `sudo xserver-xorg-input-all`, I get the error :

   ```
    Depends: xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse but it is not installable.   
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."
   ```
6. In the update manager settings, section "Additional drivers", I see two elements (that seem to correspond to my two video cards) :

   - "Nvidia corporation: unkown", for which I ticked to "Use Nvidia binary driver - version nvidia-384.111 from nvidia-384"
   - "Unknown: unknown", for which I ticked "Use microcode firmware processor for Intel CPUs from intel-microcode (free)".

   Yet **I don't know which of the two video cards is being used**, nor whether I should search towards the Nvidia gtx or towards the Intel video chipset to lower the screen brightness.

It has now been 5 days since I started attempting to get a clean Linux installation and my enthousiasm towards getting rid of buggy-costly-closed systems like Windows and Mac gets lower as my eyes are really burning.

Thanks for reading this. Any help/question is welcome.

Julien

Answer (score 0):

First Install Brightness Controller with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
sudo apt update
```

For Version 1 with up to 4 Monitor Support:

```
sudo apt install brightness-controller-simple
```

[brightness controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVYHO.png)